# onbeforeunload wait for ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible for `onbeforeunload()` function to wait for ajax result and move to a jsp based on the resultvalue or atleast show a message before unloading?

IS it possible to use setTimeOut or some custom wait function for this problem or i have to think of some other workflow

Comment: Perhaps with a synchronous call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [a synchronous XmlHttpRequest call](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=130767) ("AJAX" is a mis-nomer).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is not possible. `onbeforeunload` has very limited functionality, otherwise malicious sites could stop you from leaving their site.

Addendum: It is possible to show a message like 'You are leaving this page'. In that case, the `beforeunload()` function must return a string.

Example

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return 'Are you sure about that?';
}
```

Comment: Actually that message contains some content of the ajax result.Anyway i think this workflow is not good, i will use redirectAction and show the message using some other trick

Answer (score 0):

It is not good Idea to display alert box for waiting response from ajax. Generally you can use alert box for message for confirmation of Leaving page after ajax response.

For avoiding use of alert you can call Ajax synchronously for example

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlHttpObj=new XMLHttpRequest();
else xmlHttpObj=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
if(xmlHttpObj){
xmlHttpObj.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlHttpObj.readyState==4 && xmlHttpObj.status == 200){
 // your logic required
}
}
xmlHttpObj.open("GET", "your request url", false); // used false for synchronous call 
xmlHttpObj.send(null);
}
else{
alert("AJAX not support");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my strategy and works for me:

```
_number_of_active_ajax ++;
$.ajax({
    url: REQUEST_URL,
    timeout: 3000
})
.always(function() {
    _number_of_active_ajax --;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if(_number_of_active_debounce > 0 || _number_of_active_ajax > 0)
        return "Your question";
}
```

}

It will show a message to use if the page has an active request.