# logout user in onbeforeunload and send log to server

Tags: javascript, web-services

I'm running a silverlight web app and I want to log the user out if he closes the browser, change site etc. in case they forget to click the logout button and I want to do this in the web page that hosts the silverlight.

I tried following a tutorial: adding webservice.htc and calling the web service using javascript which looks like this

html body tag:

```
<body id="service" style="behavior:url(webservice.htc)">
```

script:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   // set web service
   service.useService(
   "https://myhost/myService/service.svc?wsdl",
   "myService");

   // call web service method
   service.myService.callService("LogInUser", -1);
}
```

the onbeforeunload does get called if i just try to show a message like

```
return "onbeforeunload called!";
```

EDIT: My web service is in SOAP and would like to consume in using javascript or or another option in my ASP.net 3.5 hosting the silverlight and is supposed to be viewed in IE8+. Any options that could complete this?

Comment: You are aware this is IE-specific syntax?

Comment: if you mean the onbeforeunload then no, it's not IE specific since it works also on chrome but if you're referring to the web service part of the method then I'm not sure though I did tested it on IE too and it didn't work.

Comment: the web service part (the .htc) is IE specific.

Comment: I'm still debugging using IE9. Not sure why it's still not working though. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the method you show, but I assume the document simply gets unloaded before anything can happen in your web service.

The only cross-browser way to do this that I know of is to make a synchronous Ajax call. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310392/onbeforeunload-wait-for-ajax-result), or in jQuery use the `async: false` flag.

I'm not sure whether this is a good idea at all though. For example, a user might have the same session open in a different browser window. With your method, closing one of them will log them out of both of them. Also, a synchronous Ajax request can freeze the browser if the network goes down.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AJAX. Is there a simple code you could add?